# Single expression for two variables where one is a function of the other

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Or... Can this be solved in a single expression?

My sense is I will need to tackle this programmatically with some sort of goal-seeking algorithm, but I wanted to check there wasn’t a single expression that would solve the problem.

I want my imaginary company to operate at $5\%$ profitability. That is my net profit expressed as a percentage of my revenue should be $5\%$.

For the sake of example, let’s say…

- My current revenue is $40,000$
- My current gross profit is $10,000$
- My current overheads are $8,500$
- (Therefore) my current net profit is $1,500$

That gives me a profitability of $1,500 / 40,000 = 0.0375$ or $3.75\%$

**The problem: I want to know how much extra gross profit I need to get to my target of $5\%$**

One very simple approach is:

$x = (n / p \cdot t) - n$

Where:

- $x$ is the extra gross profit I need
- $n$ is my current net profit
- $p$ is my current profitability level
- $t$ is my target

So, based on the above:

$(1,500 / 3.75 \cdot 5) – 1,500 = 500$

This checks out. If I had an extra $500$ then…

- My current revenue is still $40,000$ (more on this shortly!)
- My current gross profit is now $10,500$
- My current overheads are still $8,500$
- (Therefore) my current net profit is now $2,000$

This gives me a profitability of $2,000 / 40,000 = 0.05$ or $5\%$!

Hooray! Apart from the fact that is rather simple approach makes two assumptions:

1. Adding gross profit doesn’t affect add overheads
2. Adding gross profit doesn’t affect the revenue

Assumption #1 is fine. Overheads don't change as GP increases.

Assumption #2 is not. As I add GP, I also add revenue. In this model, I assume a margin of $26.5\%$. Sales are made at all sorts of margins, but $26.5\%$ is my historical average. So, for every $1$ of GP I make $3.77$ (calculated from $1$ / $0.265$) times the revenue.

So, my problem now is that when I calculate how much GP to add to get me to my $5\%$ target I need to adjust it upward to account for the fact that adding that GP will also increase my revenue and thus take me further away from my target!

I can’t shake the sense I am missing something simple and the extra GP I need can be the result of evaluating a single expression rather than having to design an algorithm.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself:

$x$ = ($m$ * (-$g$ + $e$ * $o$ + $r$ * $t$)) / ($m$ - $t$)

If using decimal fractions for $t$ and $m$

and

$x$ = ($m$ * ($g$ - $e$ * $o$ - (($r$ * $t$) / 100))) / ($t$ - $m$)

If using percentage figures for $t$ and $m$

Answer (score 0):

In the formula 
$$x=(n/p⋅t)−n$$
$n/p$ represents the current revenue, which is then multiplied by the desired profitability. Right off the bat, what we're doing is wishing more profit. Things aren't like that in the real world; we need to sell more in order to make more profit.

Let's note that GP is $25\%$ of revenue. This give current GP a value of $\frac{n}{4p}$. Our desired GP would be $\frac{n}{4p}+x$, and desired NP would be $\frac{n}{4p}+x-8500$. Desired revenue would be 4 times that of desired GP, or $\frac{n}{p}+4x$. So the following relationship must hold.
$$
\frac{\text{desired NP}}{\text{desired revenue}}=\frac{\frac{n}{4p}+x-8500}{\frac{n}{p}+4x}=t
$$

I'm assuming, of course, that "overhead" does not include any variable costs and that variable costs are linearly related to revenue.

So the extra GP becomes
$$x = \frac{8500}{1-4t}-\frac{n}{4p}$$

Comment: Sorry, but this misses that fat that my margin is not fixed. Different items sell at different margins. In the example figures, this worked out at 25% but it easily could not have done. I will add a couple of lines to the question to make that clear.